# Create an Excel Macro definition in C#

Tags: c#, excel

I want to create a Function in my C# code, which can be called from VB as if it were a Macro.

i.e. the VB code should be able to do:

```
sub vb_method
    csharp_method("some_parameters")
end sub
```

and have that call my C# method:

```
public object csharp_method(String parameter) {
    ...
}
```

I know this can be done in C++:

```
LPXLOPER retval;
LPXLOPER module;  // = something
LPXLOPER parameters[] = { module,
                         "cpp_function", "parameter_type_info",
                         "MacroName", "text",
                         2,
                         ... };
Excel4v(xlfRegister, retval, parameter_count, parameters);
```

This registers my `cpp_function` so that it can be called by the name `MacroName`.  But it's using XLOPER stuff (which is a headache), and it's in C++.

The magic `2` tells Excel to use my function as a macro.  Then my c++ code can be called from VB, or using `ExecuteExcel4Macro`.  I can also use this to register User-Defined Functions (UDF) - just use a magic `1` instead.  (more details about xlfRegister here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb687900.aspx )

C# makes it very easy to create UDFs, but I need a way to register my functions as macros instead of formulas.

So how can I have a Macro call my C# code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no convenience layer available in .NET that allows you to register macros in Excel as it is the case with user-defined functions.

The way to solve your problem would be to create a wrapper DLL in managed C++/CLI that registers the macro and then calls into the managed C# code.

With the means of reflection you should even be able to create a generic wrapper, that loads a C# assembly, enumerates all public methods (or all public methods that have a specific custom attribute), and then dynamically registers these methods.

I haven't checked it, but I assume that the mechanism for registering UDFs works in a very similar way.

Comment: I was hoping for a more native mechanism, but I'll try this.  Having a generic wrapper would definitely be better than a hardcoded wrapper.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you can make .xlls in C# or VB.NET without dealing with XLOPERs or C++ by using [Excel-Dna](http://exceldna.codeplex.com) (freely available from http://exceldna.codeplex.com).

So you could make your C# method available as a function in Excel (through a wrapper of the type 0xA3 describes) by just adding an attribute

```
[ExcelFunction(Name="MacroName")]
public object csharp_method(String parameter) 
{...}
```

Secondly, you can call both functions and macros from VBA using Application.Run. So you could say

```
  Dim result As Variant
  result = Application.Run("MacroName", mystring)
```

Comment: But I have some macros I don't want to expose as functions.  I.e., I don't want a user to be able to put "=MacroName()" into a cell.  That would be bad.  Explicitly registering my methods in C++ with XLOPERs gives me the power to register some as UDFs and some as Macros.  XLW seems to only let you do UDFs, and I think Excel-Dna is the same way.

Comment: In Excel-Dna you can mark the function as hidden: ExcelFunction(Name="MacroName", IsHidden=true)]. This registers the function as pxMacroType=0, so it is not displayed in the function wizard. Would this help?

Comment: (Users could still call the function from a worksheet, but they'd have to know the name. You could make the names obscure, adding '?'s etc.)

Comment: Or you could register the .Net library for COM interop, and then just Tools->Reference it from your VBA to call the methods.